# Import photos from portable device (iPhone, Android) using Python and Windows auto play handler

Tags: python, com, comtypes

My python application need to import photos from iPhone/Android and copy it to local hard disk. This is Windows application and need to use Windows auto play handler and COM. I have seen some example that implement it using c# language ([link is here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15626/Implement-an-Autoplay-Handler)) but I don't know how to do this using Python.

Further Googling tells python has comtypes library to use COM on windows platform but I do not find any detail documentation on how to get it done.

Comment: this may help http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/detect-device-insertion.html

Comment: registry takes reference of DLL (com server) and notification goes to that registered com server when new portable device is arrived. My problem is I don't know how to build com server that could receive notification and photos. Further I need to understand how to distribute my application as a installer that register dll etc.. Dropbox desktop client does the same thing I guess.

Comment: did you see the link I posted? thats to detect when a new device is inserted ... (you dont need the registry stuff after all I think)

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I followed the URL you posted and I'm able to detect the device now. For some reason, latest Android/iPhone device do not get mounted as drive on Windows file system and hence, I'm not able to read the content from device. I read, it is possible using MTP/PTP protocol and agin I got stuck here.